# Object in NodeList prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

The prototype of some native javascript objects can be extended to include new functions (such as `NodeList.prototype.forEach` or `NodeList.prototype.addEventListener`) which I use to allow array and element-like interaction with the `NodeList`. So far so good, but how should I add an object to the prototype which in turn has it's own functions (to allow `NodeListVar.classList.remove("class")`). I have been able to make `NodeListVar.classList().remove("class")`, by doing the following

```
NodeList.prototype.classList = function(){
    var _this = this;
    return {
        remove: function(class){
            _this.forEach(function(){
                this.classList.remove(class);
            });
        }
    }   
};
```

However I would greatly prefer the syntax to be the same as a normal `element`, thus more like:

```
NodeList.prototype.classList = {
    remove: function(class){
        //where *this* would be the nodeList and *not* the DOMWindow
        this.forEach(function(){
            this.classList.remove(class);
        });
    }
};
```

It probably isn't hard even, but I have searched google endlessly and looked through countless questions already and can't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to read: [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

You can't set objects on a prototype. All called functions will be executed in context of that static prototype object, not the NodeList itself. The object on the prototype has no reference to the current NodeList.

On normal `Element`s, every element has its own `classList` attribute, a `DOMTokenList` bound the element. You will need to do the same: Give every NodeList its own classLists instance. As you can't do that in the unavailable constructor, you will have to use a getter, as already demonstrated.

I don't think you should try to allow the same syntax on NodeLists as on Elements, because they are very different. But if you want to get rid of these brackets, you can install a [native getter function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10592753/1048572).

```
function ClassLists(nl) {
    ... // nl references the NodeList we're bound to
}
ClassLists.prototype = ...;

Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "classLists", {
    get: function() {
        return this.classLists = new ClassLists(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Static NodeList's as returned from the QuerySelector aren't that different from Elements and when developing mobile applications for android 3.0+ (as is applicable in my case) none of the disadvantages mentioned in that article are an issue. The native getter function however is new to me and should allow me to do exactly what I want yes.

Comment: Uh, they're still arrays of elements. Thats why I have named the property "classList *s*"...

Comment: They aren't arrays of elements, that's the whole issue. If they would be I wouldn't even be doing this probably :P .

Comment: And btw, it's still a classList, even though it's internally combining various classLists, from the perspective of the NodeList it's a single list of classes from which you can remove/add etc. classes.

Comment: OK, if you combine the single classList s it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement @Bergi's answer, here is a cross-browser solution:

```
function ClassList() {
    this.nodeList;
}

ClassList.prototype = {
    constructor: ClassList,

    remove: function() {
        console.log( this );
    }
};

NodeList.prototype.classList = new ClassList();

nl.classList.remove(); // ClassList object with the `nodeList` property.
```

It can't be used with the same API since it's not using `defineProperty`, but it's cross-browser. `defineProperty` is only available in IE9, and is not shimmable in IE7.

Comment: The reason I want to do this in the first place is to use the querySelectorAll more easily in a tablet application where defineProperty is available as well, as the overhead of jquery or similar libraries is bad if you already know that your browsers are quite standard compliant (webkit and theoretically firefox). Either way, giving you a upvote as it's still a valid addition :D . Thanks :)

Comment: Heh, that's a nice environment to work on. Good luck with that.

Comment: @DavidMulder btw, it looks like you'd greatly benefit from NodeComposite https://github.com/Raynos/NodeComposite

Comment: Should have known it already existed :P Although I am fine with only classList, addEventListener and forEach I guess, although I might use that library if making a general mobile web app or something along those lines. And yes, it's a *very* nice environment to work on, probably the nicest one I could work on in the past year (as it will even only running on one specific tablet).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: This solution just doesn't work, as I explained in my answer. Your ClassList object might even have a nodeList property, yes, but it's empty!!!

Comment: @Bergi: Great :S I didn't try it and didn't even look too seriously at the code as I already had a working solution based on your answer, but I gave the upvote assuming non-working code was unthinkable, but just tried it, and you are right that it doesn't work of course.