# Using prototype to behave like "setter function"

Tags: javascript

I have used a class  MC and added a "setLabel" function like this

```
MC.prototype.setLabel = function( value )
{

   this.labelTextfield.text = value  
} 

Mc.prototype.setLabel( "some random text" ) ;
```

But for some reasons, i want to be able to do something like this :

```
Mc.prototype.label = "some random text"
```

I think, if i can use setter function in prototypes, probably this can be made possible. But i am not sure, how to use setter functions for prototypes ? Any help appreciated.

Vishwas

Comment: Why are you calling the method on the prototype itself, instead of an instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define setter/getter on prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defineProperty() method for Object could be your best choice here, but I think you should be on "use strict" mode.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty