# Getters and Setters in a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, getter-setter

When using `get` in an object like this, `get` works:

```js
var people = {
  name: "Alex",
  get sayHi() {
    return `Hi, ${this.name}!`
    }
};

var person = people;

document.write(person.sayHi);
```

But with a function I get an error. How to use Getters and Setters in a function like this?

```js
function People2() {
  this.name = "Mike";
  get sayHi() {
    return `Hi, ${this.name}!`;
  }
};

var user = new People2();

document.write(user.sayHi);
```

Comment: Not sure whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592810/1048572) is a duplicate

Comment: @bergi - I searched. Didn't find a question on how to use Getters and Setters in a function and not just in an object

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin You can use `Object.defineProperty` to define getters and setters. You could also encapsulate `Person2` in a class, i. e. `class People2 { constructor() { this.name = "Mike"; } get sayHi() { return "Hi, " + this.name;} }`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the actual `get` and `set` keywords only in classes (ES2015) and object literals.

#### ECMAScript 5

In ES5, your would typically use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to implement what you're trying to achieve:

```
function People2() {
    this.name = "Mike";
}
Object.defineProperty(People2.prototype, "sayHi", {
    get: function() {
        return "Hi, " + this.name + "!";
    }
});
```

#### ECMAScript 2015

In ES2015, you could also use classes to achieve the desired behavior:

```
class People2 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "Mike";
    }
    get sayHi() {
        return `Hi, ${this.name}!`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```html
<script>
function People2(name) {
  this.name = name;  
};

People2.prototype = {
  get sayHi() {
    return `Hi, ${this.name}!`;}
};

var user = new People2('Alex');

document.write(user.sayHi);
</script>
```

or this one...

```html
<script>
function people(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Object.defineProperty(people.prototype, 'sayHi', {
    get: function() { return `Hi, ${this.name}!`; }
});

var person = new people('Alex');

document.write(person.sayHi);
</script>
```

Comment: We can also change "people.prototype" to "this" =)

Answer (score 2):

For the case you want to define a property like as `name` for a function with more control, we can use `Object.defineProperty` on function itself as following:

```
function people(name) {

    //this.name = name; //this can be modified freely by caller code! we don't have any control

    var _name = name; //use a private var to store input `name`
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        get: function() { return _name; },  //we can also use `return name;` if we don't use `name` input param for other purposes in our code
        writable: false, //if we need it to be read-only
        //... other configs
    });

};

var person = new people('Alex');
console.log(person.name); //writes Alex
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, use this:

```
function People2() {
  this.name = "Mike";
  this.__defineGetter__("sayHi", function() {
    return `Hi, ${this.name}!`;
  });
};
```

Comment: `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__`  is deprecated and non-standard. [Do not use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__).