# Is using es6 class in node.js useful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, es6-class

I just wondering while working on node.js projects. Should I declare a `class` in a `function`, to use it for example globally like `let task = new Task(params);`?

## I'm thinking about two different ways, to handle classes

### Case: no class

```
'use strict'

/**
 *
 * @param taskId
 * @param timeStamp
 * @constructor
 *
 */
function task(taskId, timeStamp) {

  this.taskId = taskId;
  this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

/**
 *
 * type {task}
 *
 */
module.exports = task;
```

I'm requiring `task.js` as `let task = require('./task.js');` somewhere. For example in `globals.js`, witch is required as `let g` in `app.js`.

Anyway, it's working like a charm, to create somewhere else a new `Task` like I wrote above: `let task = new g.task('someTaskId', varForTStamp);`

---

### Case: class

```
'use strict'

/**
 *
 * @constructor
 *
 */
function task() {

  class Task {
    
    /**
     *
     * @param taskId
     * @param timeStamp
     */
     constructor(taskId, timeStamp) {

       this.taskId = taskId;
       this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
     }

     //in task is no get or set method needed
   }

/**
 *
 * type {task}
 *
 */
 module.exports = task;
```

Same thing here. Call somewhere else a `new Task` by using the same requires and definitions.

Do I have to declare a class if I have to work with `get()` and `set()` methods? Not even if I need to work with `get()` and `set()`, I have to use `class`. It would work the same way like in `class`.
Both ways working good and there are no problems or exceptions.

But what is happened in the background of **requireJS**, **node.js**? Should I use a certain technique, to write clear code for better performance?

Is there a better way to handle new objects across a node.js project? How do you manage it and handle with that kind of differences?

Comment: Regarding the `get` and `set` methods see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367348/getters-and-setters-in-a-function-javascript

Comment: The question is too unspecific. At this point there's no need for a class at all. If your real code is more complex, consider providing it and not a dummy class, this may be important. *requireJS* - what does it have to do with all of these? *Should I use a certain technique, to write clear code for better performance?* - native classes have some performance benefits in latter engine versions, but this is not a concern for the majority of cases and can be considered preliminary optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually do not need to return a class from a function (your second code snippet). You can just directly export the class.

This is probably the best way to do it:

test.js:

```
class Test{
  constructor(info){
    this._info=info;
  }

  getInfo(){
    return this._info;
  }
}

module.exports=Test;
```

main.js:

```
const Test=require('./test');
const myTest=new Test("hello");
const myOtherTest=new Test("world");
console.log(myTest.getInfo());
console.log(myOtherTest.getInfo());
```

Also you should not have to use a `global.js` file. For example instead of doing

```
const g=require('./global');
const myTest=new g.Test("abc");
```

You should directly require Test:

```
const Test=require('./test');
const myTest=new Test("abc");
```

Comment: Why should not I use a **global.js** to wrap functions i a object, and require it in **main.js**? Is there a security aspect too? Or just a recommendation to use modules in a good separated way?

Comment: @MaximilianFixl there is no security consideration but it makes your code easier to follow. It is also probably more efficient if you want to use browserify

Comment: thanks for your reply! It really makes sence to require only needed modules. But, browserify does‘nt make sence to me, because I‘m only on server and not on client. Best regards!