# Javascript "set __proto__" in console

Tags: javascript, syntax, console

I am wondering that, what is the `set __proto__` in Javascript Console. I searched on Google, but there is only `__proto__` in results.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Looks like a setter. The value is a function, right? And there's also a `get __proto__` alongside of it?

Comment: @JaromandaX & co. - If you expand even a default empty `{}` object's `__proto__` in the console it shows properties/methods including `get __proto__:__proto__()` and `set __proto__:__proto__()`. (At least, Chrome does that.) I assume that's what this is about. This is one of those situations when a screenshot would probably help make things clearer, but I believe the OP is asking about default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn - it looks slightly different in Firefox - `set: set __protot__()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Circle = function () {};
var shape = {};
var circle = new Circle();
shape.__proto__ = circle;
console.log(shape.__proto__ === circle); // true
```

**Like the above code, maybe it was not `set__proto__`and more like `set.__proto__`**

`var set= {};`

Comment: If you expand an object's `__proto__` in the console it shows properties/methods including `get __proto__:__proto__()` and `set __proto__:__proto__()`. (At least, Chrome does that.) There's no `set` object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype -
like this one ?