# Compare value of two property in object and change flag to true if value different

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have below object and want to boolean flag true if new value different form old value and false if not

**Original object:**

```
{ 
  userName: 'user@gmail.com',
  email: 'rakesh@gmail.com',
  firstName: 'Naresh',
  lastName: 'Kumar',   
  oldEmail: 'kuamr@gmail.com',
  oldFirstName: 'Rakesh',
  oldLastName: 'Kumar'
}
```

**After transformation**:

```
{ 
  userName: 'user@gmail.com',
  email: 'rakesh@gmail.com',
  firstName: 'Naresh',
  lastName: 'Kumar',

  isFirstNameChanged: true,
  isEmailChanged: true,
  isFirstNameChanged: false,

  oldEmail: 'kuamr@gmail.com',
  oldFirstName: 'Rakesh',
  oldLastName: 'Kumar'
}
```

Is there any way to do it in lodash?

Comment: which two values to be compare? & do you want to modify the same object or create new object?

Comment: oldemail to email, firstName to oldFirstName and lastName to oldLastName

Comment: modify existing object with flags

Comment: `obj.isFirstNameChanged = obj.firstName !== obj.oldFirstName`. Repeat for each of the others.

Comment: Maybe you can use a getter\settter property..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array with the keys for updating the properties with a check.

```js
function update(object) {
    const capitalize = s => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
    
    ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'].forEach(k => object['is' + capitalize(k) + 'Changed'] = object[k] === object['old' + capitalize(k)]);
}

var object = { userName: 'user@gmail.com', email: 'rakesh@gmail.com', firstName: 'Naresh', lastName: 'Kumar', oldEmail: 'kuamr@gmail.com', oldFirstName: 'Rakesh', oldLastName: 'Kumar' };

update(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```