# how to define setter and getter in a class in javascript in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on GAS(Google Apps Script) where I use ES5 javascript.

I defined a class as follows:

```
var Test = function(a){
  this._a = a;
}

Test.prototype.doSomething = function(){
  //do something here
}
```

And then, I want to add setter and getter for `this._a` in the same way as Test.prototype.doSomething is defined.

I found this code to define setter and getter in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype):

```
var o = {
    a: 7,
    get b() {
        return this.a + 1;
    },
    set c(x) {
        this.a = x / 2
    }
};
```

However, I don't know how to apply this way to my case.

Could you please tell me how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Apps Script is an interesting dialect of JavaScript in that it is both very out of date (though I understand that's going to get fixed) and yet has the odd smattering of modern things in it.

There are a couple of older ways to do what you're trying to do, hopefully one of them works in GAS:

### `Object.defineProperty`

This is still modern, but was added long enough ago GAS may have it: Using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), like this:

```
var Test = function(a){
    this._a = a;
};

Test.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    //do something here
};

Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "a", {
    get: function() {
        return this._a;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        this._a = value;
    },
    configurable: true
});
```

### Using `get` and `set` Syntax

...to define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), as in your example in the question.

```
var Test = function(a){
    this._a = a;
};

Test.prototype = {
    constructor: Test,
    doSomething: function(){
      //do something here
    },
    get a() {
        return this._a;
    },
    set a(value) {
        this._a = a;
    }
};
```

Note that when you completely replace the object on the `prototype` property like that, you want to be sure to define the `constructor` property as shown above (it's defined that way by default in the object you get automatically, but if you replace it, naturally it's not automatically provided on the replacement).

### The REALLY Old Way

I doubt GAS supports it, but just in case, the **really** old way to do it uses [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) and [`__defineSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineSetter__) like this:

```
var Test = function(a){
    this._a = a;
};

Test.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    //do something here
};

Test.prototype.__defineGetter__("a", function() {
    return this._a;
});
Test.prototype.__defineSetter__("a", function(value) {
    this._a = value;
});
```

This was never officially part of ECMAScript, but it was in the dialect of JavaScript from Mozilla for years (and probably still is, for backward compatibility).

Comment: Hi.. GAS was updated to v8 a month or two ago. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details. However op might still be using old engine. So, I think this is useful

Comment: Yes, I know "Using get and set Syntax" way but as you explained, I don't want it to happen that it completely replace the object on the prototype property. So, I apply "Object.defineProperty" way. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for you advice. Yes, I know v8 update. But It has some issue so I have postponed using v8 because of this issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841

Comment: @TheMaster - Thanks! I'd heard that was in the works, I'm glad to hear it's gone ahead!

Comment: @Herbert - `defineProperty` worked? That's good to know. I was about 75% on whether it would... :-)