# Why doesn't the setter method body get called when using Javascript class syntax?

Tags: javascript

```js
 class Person{
    
      constructor(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
      }
      get getName(){
        return this.name;
      }
      set setName(name){
        if (typeof name === 'number'){
          this.name = name;
        }else{
          this.name = 'joesy';
        }
      }
    
    }
    const p1 = new Person('jack',9);
    console.log(`${p1.name}`);
    p1.name = 11;
    console.log(`${p1.name}`);
```

I want to be able to check that the parameter passed into the set method is a number and not a string, but it seems that no matter how I write the if statement inside setName(), calling `p1.name = value` will always set `value` to x.

Comment: The method names for your setter and getter functions represent the actual property names of the objects. You're setting the `name` property, but the setter will only be called if you set the `setName` property.

Comment: You cannot have a simple "name" property and also setters and getters; it's one or the other.

Comment: `p1.name`, `p1.getName` and `p1.setName` are three different properties in your code.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype) will be helpfull, I think

Comment: FM is always good - read it first - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Also, JavaScript getters and setters are rather peculiar in that the variable name stays the same; in Java you'd do something like `getName`, but in JS it's `get name`.

Comment: @code There is nothing peculiar about that; Java simply technically doesn't offer getters and setters. These exist only **by convention** in Java.

Comment: @connexo that's the peculiar part. In most languages you manually create getters and setters, and conventionally prepend `get` to the variable name; this is where JavaScript defers.

Comment: @code I see nothing peculiar in that. You could work with the very same conventions in Javascript as well (which you'd do e.g. if you want to allow access to private properties), but it also offers a technical solution as an integral part of the language itself, instead of just a convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects can have two different types of properties:

1. data properties and
2. accessor properties (getter/setter).

Data properties simply store values assigned to them (if they are *writable*) and return these stored values when read.

**Accessor properties do not store values *at all***. Instead they work as functions that are executed whenever read access (getter) or write access/assignment to the property (setter) happens.

Here's a basic example:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    // data properties
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;    
  }
  
  // accessor property
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  
  set fullName(name) {
    let [firstName, lastName] = name.split(' ');
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;  
  }
}


const p1 = new Person('John', 'Doe');
const p2 = new Person();
p2.fullName = 'Christine Smith';

console.log(p1.firstName, p1.lastName, p1.fullName);
console.log(p2.firstName, p2.lastName, p2.fullName);
```